# How to export more than 16000 rows in bigquery table to local machine as CSV file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to export output of my select statement in Bigquery. There is "Save Results" option available but it has limit of 16,000 rows.

How can i export more than that?

Answer (score 1):

If your data has more than 16,000 rows you'd need to save the result of your query as a BigQuery Table. [image: BigQuery options]

Afterwards, [export the data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) from the table into Google Cloud Storage using any of the available options (such as the Cloud Console, API, bq or client libraries).

Finally, you can use any of the available methods in Google Cloud Storage (Cloud Console, API, gsutil or client libraries) to [download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) the CSV file within your local environment.

Since for the time being you [can't export data from a Table directly to a local file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations).

Comment: Thanks Daniel Ocando, but we will need to generate reports many times. and it be very time consuming to do this process everytime. also creating this much tables is not possible in our dataset

Comment: I would totally agree that using the Cloud Console will be the wrong path to explore if you are in need of some sort of automation.

Comment: You could use a script that uses [bq mk](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_mk) to create the table, [bq query --destination_table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_query) to perform your query, [bq extract -destination_forma CSV](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) to transfer to GCS and finally `gsutil cp gs://[my-bucket]/[my-csv-file] .` to [download to your cd](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#gsutil).

Comment: If you have some sort of limitation in the amount of tables that you can use, you could either [set an expiration time for the table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time) with the [bq update command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_update) or delete it on it's entirety by using [bq rm](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_rm).

Comment: Sadly you won't be able to export a file directly to your local PC without complying with the 16,000 row limitation. But there is an open [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/129926373) that I recommend you to star and follow.

Comment: There was a typo in one of my comments. I meant `bq extract --destination_format CSV` in order to transfer to GCS.

Comment: what you think about bigquery client?
Can i use python bigquery client to run query and save its output to csv?
or there is also any row limit?

Comment: Yes! Using any of the [available client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries) will also be a possibility. You won't be limited by row limit, rather by [max response size](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#limitations). But notice that when querying large results a similar approach as described above will necessarily need to be done using a table and [cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries).

Comment: There are plenty of examples within the community, such as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172749/how-to-extract-a-csv-from-bigquery-and-send-it-to-an-external-server-with-python).

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite easier step by using the [export function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement). You can perform a simple query to export directly to GCS

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://MyBucket/path/to/file*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=',') AS
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE condition.
```

However, it's greatly possible that several files are generated. And thus you have to get all of them with gsutil.

The advantage of Daniel's solution, is that you can choose to export the table to only one file.